# How to Zero Pad in Image processing (FFT)

Tags: image, numpy, fft, convolution, deconvolution

I am new to image processing and this question is more theoretical.

Suppose I have a 5x5 image and a 3x3 kernel. I now want to use FFT2 to convolve the image. From what I understand you would need to pad the image with zeroes so it would look like

```
0000000 
0iiiii0 
0iiiii0 
0iiiii0 
0iiiii0
0iiiii0 
0000000
```

to accomodate for the kernel and the kernel to

```
0000000 
0000000 
00kkk00 
00kkk00 
00kkk00
0000000 
0000000
```

and im then using `np.fft.fft2` to convert them both into their fourier domain versions, then multiplying and using `np.fft.ifft2` to invert. After this I get imaginary values. Is this correct and should I be getting these imaginary values? If so what should I do next?

Here is the code from which I am getting imaginary values:

```py
conv_kernel = np.zeros(image.shape)
    
for i in range(len(kernel)):
    for j in range(len(kernel[0])):
        conv_kernel[i,j] = kernel[i,j]

fourier_domain_img = np.fft.fft2(image)
fourier_domain_kernel = np.fft.fft2(conv_kernel)

multiplication_result = np.multiply(fourier_domain_img, fourier_domain_kernel)

output = np.fft.ifft2(multiplication_result)
```

Note that the image has been padded as mentioned previously with 0s around the edges and the kernel has been shifted to the top left and saved in `conv_kernel`.

`output` gives me imaginary values. Output snippet:

````
0.34701525+7.90350302e-19j 0.24993464-1.97207468e-17j
  0.25917211-7.08625583e-17j 0.26527233-7.02379773e-17j
  0.25986928-8.79273688e-17j 0.30030501-1.20158599e-16j
  0.41908497-6.28590074e-17j 0.56592593-7.59364420e-17j
  0.66858388-1.28485529e-17j 0.63956427+1.46374819e-17j
  0.52383442-2.31376484e-17j 0.30623094-7.88434060e-18j]]
complex128```
````

Comment: No, you should not be getting imaginary values (the imaginary component should be zero up to rounding errors). Please check the magnitude of the imaginary components w.r.t. the real values. And please show the code that produces imaginary values.

Comment: Also, your kernel there is shifted, which means the result of the convolution will be shifted as well. The origin for the FFT is in the top-left corner. The central element of the kernel should be at (0,0). You can do this by calling `np.fft.ifftshift` on your padded kernel. There is no need to shift your image (the origin there doesn't matter), the FFTs, or the result of the convolution; only the padded kernel should be shifted.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've shared some code, unfortunately this is probably all I can share.

Comment: If you wish to pad an image which is represented as a numpy array, you can use [np.pad](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

Comment: yes, I have padded the image with np.pad

Comment: The imaginary components of these results is approximately zero, extremely tiny (relative to the real components), numbers like 0.000000000000000075936442

Comment: I have tried using only the real components. By using ```output = np.real(output)``` however that still does not give me an accurate answer. I am trying to replicate ```scipy.ndimage.convolve(a,b,mode ="nearest" ``` I have done some post processing to extract the image from the output and apply clamp-to-edge afterwards. The resulting difference is very (very) small which leads me to believe it has something to do with the small values in the complex part of ```output```

Comment: A very small difference with `scipy.ndimage.convolve` is due to rounding errors. The same reason that the complex values are not exactly zero. You cannot expect computations to be more precise than floating-point computations allow. The FFT tends to have an error in the order of `eps * sum(img)`.

Comment: Your kernel padding is not as you described earlier, and is wrong.